# matching customer id value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

new to learning sql/postgresql and have been hunting all over looking for help with a query to find only the matching id values in a table so i can pull data from another table for a learning project.  I have been trying to use the count command,  which doesn't seem right, and struggling with group by.

here is my table

```
id  acct_num    sales_tot   cust_id date_of_purchase
1   9001        1106.10     116     12-Jan-00
2   9002         645.22     125     13-Jan-00
3   9003        1096.18     137     14-Jan-00
4   9004        1482.16     118     15-Jan-00
5   9005        1132.88     141     16-Jan-00
6   9006         482.16     137     17-Jan-00
7   9007        1748.65     147     18-Jan-00
8   9008        3206.29     122     19-Jan-00
9   9009        1184.16     115     20-Jan-00
10  9010        2198.25     133     21-Jan-00
11  9011         769.22     141     22-Jan-00
12  9012        2639.17     117     23-Jan-00
13  9013         546.12     122     24-Jan-00
14  9014        3149.18     116     25-Jan-00
```

trying to write a simple query to only find matching customer id's, and export them to the query window.

Comment: Edit our question and show the results you want.

Comment: What is a *matching customer id*?

Comment: Please tell what should be the correct answer with this data, what is the query you tried and how is it's answer wrong

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [JOIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html)